# How to find out if Action has captured values in C# 7

Tags: c#, lambda

At the moment i'm porting some old code to C# 7. I have a problem due to a change of the language. In C# 5 an lambda that does not capture anything was static:

```
(handler.Method.IsStatic == true)
```

that is no longer the case in C# 7, where all local-function, lambdas, ..., are local functions.

So I need find out in another way if the Action has captured some values, to port the following code.

```
void add<U>(U target, Action<U> handler)
{
     var hasHandlerCapturedSomething=!handler.Method.IsStatic;
     if(hasHandlerCapturedSomething)throw new Exception("Only static handlers are allowed!");
    //...
}
```

Comment: Just curious: what is the purpose of `hasHandlerCapturedSomething`? Why you need throw exception in case handler have captured values?

Comment: You could count the number of fields with handler.Target.GetType().GetFields().Length.  But I suspect that Roslyn will throw you for a loop or two, ymmv.

Comment: I don't know hot to use the number of all fields to get the info, that i want. Can you be a little bit more concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest i got. Is the following.

```
static bool hasCapturedValues(Action a) { return isStatic(a.Method); }
static bool hasCapturedValues(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    var fields = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Static |
                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).ToList();
    return methodInfo.IsStatic|| fields.All(f=>f.IsStatic);
}
```

The only thing that does not work is the following scenario

```
class Foo{
   int i;
   void bar(){}
}

var foo=new Foo();
Action barAction=foo.bar;
Console.WriteLine(hasCapturedValues(barAction)); //print true
```

This was close enough for me, but if someone has something nicer. Let me know.